# Use PowerShell as a console, as if it was created with AllocConsole

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is this possible? I wish `AllocConsole` (or a set of function calls behaving the same way) to allocate a PowerShell window instead of a normal console window.

If it's not possible, can I `CreateProcess` and attach my input and output to a PowerShell instance?

Comment: `PowerShell.exe` is separate process. you need use `CreateProcess` for create it. and can redirect input/output to pipe for example

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell also uses a "normal console window" because there is only one console window type. Cmd.exe and PowerShell.exe are not special, they just use the normal Windows console API functions.

If you want to control stdin and stdout then you must create some pipes with [`CreatePipe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152(v=vs.85).aspx) and set `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` and the handles in `STARTUPINFO` before calling `CreateProcess`. See [this MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx) for details. You can write the stdout data to a console window you create with `AllocConsole` if you also want to display the output. Note that when you redirect stdin/stdout the interactive console functions no longer work.

Comment: What I want seems like it would require explicit support from PowerShell. There is no indication that PowerShell ever looks at its assigned IO handles, let alone displays information from them. The only solution to me seems to be to launch PowerShell with arguments telling it to run my program.